# How to convert string to DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have a string and I want to convert it from string to datetime. When I'm trying its giving exception. 
Please suggest me how to do.

```
string stime = "2014-02-02T24:00:00";
DateTime dtStartDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(stime);
```

Comment: `DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("your string goes here")l`

Comment: getting same exception.

Comment: @user3264676 Why did you accept the wrong answer? Take a look at my answer also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22061641/447156

Comment: hello @SonerGönül let him decide! I agree noticing the '24' but what ever he posted its just a sample date now please dont say that todays date is also wrong..!
Looking towards his score he is newbee...right? And he has already mentioned that it "throws exception" hence to prevent exception the solution i have given..

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE Of course his decide but Stack Overflow is not a place people can get help one by one. **Stack Overflow is for Internet**. In the future, people can find this question after a search. And when they found, they should see the right answer. OP should not be select the wrong answer at all. His string includes `T` character for example, but your answer does not. That's makes huge difference between your answer and question.

Comment: edited my answer @SonerGönül as per your requirement and tested too..and it works! :)

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE Your answer still doesn't answer the _how to parse_ part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is useful—it does the same thing as `DateTime.Parse`, BUT

### DOES NOT THROW ANY EXCEPTIONS

It returns `true` if the parse succeeded, and `false` otherwise.

```
protected  void Foo()
    {
        // Use DateTime.TryParse when input is valid.
        string input = "2014-02-02T04:00:00";//"2014-02-02";
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out dateTime))
        {
            lblresult.Text = dateTime.ToString();
        }
        else {
            lblresult.Text = "invalid";
        }
}
```

**[See Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparse)**

Comment: Only U got the question correctly. :)

Comment: How this could be helpful? You didn't even try to parse OP's string. And @user3264676 why you selected this as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

All answers are wrong, unfortunately. I'm really shocked no one even tested their examples.

.NET doesn't support `24` as an hour. It is not possible to parse your string with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. But [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) does that. It *can* parse the value but value parsed as next day's midnight. That's probably because there is no standart `24:00` as an hour.

From [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00);

> In the 24-hour time notation, the day begins at midnight, 00:00, and
>   the last minute of the day begins at 23:59. Where convenient, the
>   notation 24:00 may also be used to refer to midnight at the end of a
>   given date – **that is, 24:00 of one day is the same time as 00:00 of
>   the following day.**

<strike>I can't install *NodaTime* right now</strike> I installed NodaTime and <strike>but</strike> this example <strike>probably work</strike> works..

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "2014-02-02T24:00:00";
        var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture
             ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        var dt = pattern.Parse(s).Value;
        Console.WriteLine(pattern.Format(dt)); // 2014-02-03T00:00:00
    }
}
```