# How to ignore offset from string datetime

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time

I have been searching to convert string to datetime with ignoring the offset.
I have a string with local date time as `2017-02-13T12:11:03.303 +01:00` i want to ignore the offset part and string should be converted to `2017-02-13 12:11:03.303` as datetime format. I searched google but could not find one.

Referred [How to convert string to DateTime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060758/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-in-c)

Not a duplicate of [DateTime.ParseExact, Ignore the timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676856/datetime-parseexact-ignore-the-timezone) as while searching didn't know its realted to `DateTimeOffset`.Searched using layman terms and no proper result found.

Comment: You _can't_ have a `2017-02-13T12:11:03.303 +01:00` as a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` instance doesn't have a UTC Offset.

Comment: @Soner I don’t think the request was for “2017-02-13T12:11:03.303 +01:00 as a DateTime”. I believe he states he has that as a string and wants it as a DateTime without the offset. I also don’t think this is a duplicate as the linked answer returns a DateTimeOffset where this request is for a DateTime. It seems mm8’s answer is correct and complete for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `DateTimeOffset.Parse` method:

```
string s = "2017-02-13T12:11:03.303 +01:00";
DateTime dt = DateTimeOffset.Parse(s, null).DateTime;
```